# Visual Studio code debugger ignores skipFiles section

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular project where I am only writing TypeScript.
I do not want the debugger to jump in any javascript file, so I followed the instructions I found about VS Code launch.json files.
My file looks like this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/apps",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "skipFiles": [
         "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js",
         "${workspaceRoot}/**/*.js",
         "${workspaceRoot}/*.js",
       ]
    }
  ]
```

The last line of skipFiles should indicate, that I do not want the debugger to jump in any .js files.
But this seems to be ignored... the compiler still jumps in Angular output files that I am not interested in... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the path of the Angular files that the debugger is jumping to?